# Changing UITableViewCell width to fit a UIImageView outside of the cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I would like to know the best way/correct way to achieve from following layout? I want to place an UIImageView outside of UITableViewCell in a UITableView with static cells.

[image: Screenshot of what i'm trying to achieve]

I have done the following by subclassing UITableViewCell for the cells in section 1 using the following code

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    frame.size.width -= 125.0;
    [super setFrame:frame];
}
```

In the UITableViewController's viewDidLoad I add the UIImageView and position it according to the width of the custom UITableViewCell.

This sort of works, but i'm not sure how to deal with rotation and also if what i've done so far would be the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to produce what I wanted using the follow, this is proberly not the best way or cleanest way but as no one from StackOverFlow gave any better suggestions I thought I better answer this.

I subclassed the first 3 UITableViewCells and set a frame size to take into account the size of my image.

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
float cellWidth = (frame.size.width - 345);
frame.size.width = cellWidth;

[super setFrame:frame];
```

}

Then in my UITableViewController's viewDidLoad I create and position the UIImageView using the first static cell in the tableview as an IBOutlet ("firstCell"). I then set the autoResizingMask which sorts out rotation and finally add the UIImageView to the view.

```
//Create and position the image view
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((firstCell.frame.size.width), (firstCell.frame.origin.y + 70), 300, 137)];

// Add border and round corners of image view to make style look a little like tableviewcells
[imageView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.5].CGColor];
[imageView.layer setBorderWidth:2.0];
[imageView.layer setCornerRadius:5.0];
[imageView setClipsToBounds:YES];

//Set the image in the image view
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultPicture.png"];
imageView.image = image;

//Set resizing of image view for when view is rotated
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;
imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

//Add tap gesture for imageview to initiate taking picture.
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
UITapGestureRecognizer *imageViewTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(takePicture:)];
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:imageViewTap];

//Add image view to view
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

[image: landscape]
[image: portrait]

This has not been fully tested and i'm sure isn't a great implementation, but its a starting point for the effect i'm after. Please reply if you know of a better way.

Note: The above code is written for my app on the iPad but screenshots are from testing I did on iPhone

Answer (score 0):

there are differnt ways to do it. one is to set the width of table view less as you showd in pic 2nd is to use custom table view cell and on required cell add image so that your cell data as well as image will be shown. i think custom cell would be the better solution. tell me if you are asking the same thing what i answered, if no, then i review my answer thank.

Comment: I don't want to change the UITableView width because that will affect the other rows in the second section. I want to use the Custom cell approach, but want to know the correct way to implement this.

Comment: @MattPrice so you want how to implement custom cell.

Comment: @vishiphone have a look at my answer below. I have done what I wanted. I can't mark it as answered for 10hrs