# how to group few cells and add an image on left side of the group like add new contact form

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, user-interface, uistoryboard

[image: screenshot of add new contact form]

Please Explain this first section of the form how can we build similar form in which the top 3 cells have and image add option on left side. any terminologies and guide references would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't achieve this using multiple cells (for first name, last name and company). You can have on cell in which you have the image on the left side and 3 text fields on the right side.

Comment: found this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419982/changing-uitableviewcell-width-to-fit-a-uiimageview-outside-of-the-cell) but don't know if it is the right and only way of doing this